# Can a program span on 0 memory cells? If so, where is it hosted? (where it "sits down")?

Tags: memory-management

[In this question post, one of the answers is](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148412/can-a-software-program-be-stored-in-just-one-memory-cell):

> ```
> You can even store a software program in 0 memory cells!
>
> All you need to do is to define a programming language in which the
> empty program has a defined meaning. For example, you can define a
> programming language that is just like Python, except the empty
> program prints the string "Hello, World!" to the console; let's call
> this programming language Python++.
>
> Now you can store a Python++ "Hello, World" program in 0 memory cells.
> ```

I read this answer several times but I cannot understand what the author intended. I tried to ask for clarification which the author read for sure (before declining my edit) but sadly didn't relate to.

Can a program span on 0 memory cells? If so, where is it hosted? (where it "sits down" if not in the memory --- any software memory type [Central-Processing-Unit-memory/Hard-Drive-Disk-memory/etc.)?

Comment: Try walking us through what you think the answer means, and where you find you get lost or perceive a conflict with something you know. The more precisely you can identify your points of confusion, the better users here can address them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scheme the author is using, the *program* can occupy zero memory cells. The thing you are using to *hold* the program might take some memory though.

Consider for instance a file on your hard disc. That file will still have a file name, size information, and other metadata in your file system, and that metadata takes up space. But the "payload" of the file - the section containing the file's data contents - is allowed to have zero length, and take up no space at all on disc. See [zero-byte file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-byte_file).

Or, when you load the program into an interpreter, you might store its text/symbols in an array variable inside that interpreter's program. For the example of a zero memory cell program, that array would have zero length. The variable would still occupy some memory in your interpreter's address space - for instance, in a managed language it would likely store some type information and a start/end pointer or length - but the part of that space used by the "zero memory cell program" could indeed be nothing at all.

```
Array
  type: program_symbol
  start: null_pointer
  length: 0
```

Your interpreter would then have a check something like:

```
if (programContents.length == 0) {
   // Do the defined operation for a zero-length program.
   Print("Hello World");
} else {
   // Iterate over the program's contents and interpret each symbol...
}
```

This is how we could implement a programming language like the author of the original answer describes, where a zero-length program still does something. Any one thing that we choose, in fact!

I hope it's clear, this is not a useful way to write new software. It's just an edge case in how we define a program. If a program is a sequence of symbols that is valid and interpretable according to a chosen programming language definition, then we can choose to define our programming language so that the empty sequence is a valid program with a given interpretation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I understood correctly, we can define program X which by itself, externally defines program Y (program Y has zero bits in it) and we can check if program Y indeed has zero bits in it; if it doesn't have any bits, we will do an action with program X.

Comment: Well, I hope I understood correctly...